# What kind of flags/permissions implementations should be?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. How should I implement permissions, that can be constantly added/changed ?

Now I have this:

- my database table scheme has field `flags`
- I can select what I need via, for example, `SELECT * from some_table WHERE flags&'.FLAG_CLOSED|FLAG_ACTIVE.'='.FLAG_CLOSED|FLAG_ACTIVE;`
- all flags are constants inside the code

sample code, just for figuring out what I mean (it's not real code, it's even not tested):

```
class Sample {

    const FLAG_ACTIVE  = 0x01;
    const FLAG_CLOSED  = 0x02;
    const FLAG_DELETED = 0x04;

    private $db;

    public function __construct(...) {
       /* ... */
    }

    public function getClosed() {
        $flags = self::FLAG_ACTIVE | self::FLAG_CLOSED;
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `flags`&'.$flags.'='.$flags;
        $stmt = $this->db->query($query);
        return $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

It's easy to get filtered result via just one field compare, but it's so annoying to change it inside the code.

Another way to that is to make additional table, that should have flag and value. But what will be more efficient? Should value have a bit-field-based value (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, .. etc) or something else, like 'CLOSED', 'ACTIVE' ?

In this two cases table row will looks like:

```
id, description, flags
===============
1, 'test', 0x12
1, 'test', 'CLOSED,ACTIVE'
```

in the second case I need to filter by `WHERE flags like '%CLOSED%' and flags like '%ACTIVE%' ?

Oh.. here is the another way to implements flags. To make a table that has an `Id` and `Flag`. Like:

```
Id,  flag
========
1, CLOSED
1, ACTIVE
```

may be here is exists more efficient implementation ?

p.s. sry for inconvenience, it's first question, be patient

p.p.s. I don't need to repeat this scheme exactly, I've just request an advice, how do that with more efficient way, it can be absolutely simple implementation without any bit-fields values.

Comment: If you really want to do this, take a look at the `SET` datatype. But I recommend that you just make a table where each flag is in a separate row, rather than combining them as bits, because bit fields like this can't be indexed.

Comment: @Barmar , thanks for advice, it's looks that I need, but can I extend SET via new flags without any hurts, for example assume, that table has 700k records? And can I retrieve all of the SET values from database? and what about efficience, although I can use a cache...

Comment: As long as you don't change the order of the elements of the `SET`, you can extend it with no problems. `SET` is implemented internally as a bit field just like you're doing.

Comment: But wanting to extend `SET` and obtain a list of all such values are both compelling reasons for using the related table that @Barmar suggested rather than embedding such characteristics in your schema definition.

Comment: `SET` is not efficient, they can't be indexed. Internally, it's just like your `WHERE` clause, so it has to do a full table scan to match an element. That's why I recommend you use a separate table rather than either of these methods.

Comment: @Barmar .. oh.. can you say what scheme of table will be more efficient to work with (all flags in one field, or every flag needs to be separated, or may be something else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a single flag field for this, use a table with a separate row for each flag.

```
CREATE TABLE flags (
    thing_id INT,
    flag VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (thing_id, flag),
    FOREIGN KEY (thing_id) REFERENCES things (id),
    INDEX (flag)
);
```

Rows will look like:

```
thing_id flag
1       active
1       closed
2       closed
3       deleted
3       active
```

Then to find all the things with a particular flag, you join the table:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM things AS t
JOIN flags as f ON f.thing_id = t.id
WHERE f.flag = 'closed';
```

To get all of a thing's flags, use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT t.*, GROUP_CONCAT(f.flag) AS flags
FROM things AS t
JOIN flags as f ON f.thing_id = t.id
WHERE t.id = :thing_id
```

If you want to prevent creating flags that shouldn't exist, you could make the `flag` column a foreign key into a `flag_names` table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's all (and even more) what I need to hear.. Very appreciated.

Comment: As a suggestion - It can be improved with some limits, if the value will be an int (1,2,4...32). And we can get all the flags without `concat`, but with `sum`. A limit - we can't have more than 32 / 64 flags per `thing`, w/o support of bigint. In most of the cases it's enough.

Comment: In fact, our company had a table with the a numeric `flags` column, and we switched to this method when we overflowed it. For the sake of all the applications that were written to use numeric flags, we added a stored function to convert.